# node.js REPL over socket hangs up when CTRL + C or CTRL + D is pressed

Tags: node.js, sockets, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to use REPL over socket like a telnet connection, but when I press CTRL + C or CTRL + D, or an error is produced, the socket connection hangs and doesn't respond to anything.

The node.js code is:

```
var net = require("net");
var connections = 0;

// Socket port 5001
net.createServer(function (socket) {
  connections += 1;
  var server = require("repl").start(
      'session:' + connections + ' > ', 
      socket
  );
  server.rli.on('exit', function() {
    socket.end();
  });
}).listen(5001);

// Console
var server = require("repl").start('session:' + (++connections) + ' > ', null);
```

and from other terminal I run:

```
telnet localhost 5001
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is a linux problem.

I've tried a [Telnet server example with node](http://www.davidmclifton.com/2011/07/22/simple-telnet-server-in-node-js/).
When I run on window, every key I press is processed by `receiveData` function, but in linux no.
In linux is processed line per line and not character per character.

Here is the code I've probed:

```
var net = require('net');
var sockets = [];

/*
 * Cleans the input of carriage return, newline
 */
function cleanInput(data) {
    return data.toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
}

/*
 * Method executed when data is received from a socket
 */
function receiveData(socket, data) {
    var cleanData = cleanInput(data);
    if(cleanData === "@quit") {
        socket.end('Goodbye!\n');
    }
    else {
        for(var i = 0; i<sockets.length; i++) {
            if (sockets[i] !== socket) {
                sockets[i].write(data);
            }
        }
    }
    socket.write('Data: ' + data);
}

/*
 * Method executed when a socket ends
 */
function closeSocket(socket) {
    var i = sockets.indexOf(socket);
    if (i != -1) {
        sockets.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

/*
 * Callback method executed when a new TCP socket is opened.
 */
function newSocket(socket) {
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.write('Welcome to the Telnet server!\n');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        receiveData(socket, data);
    })
    socket.on('end', function() {
        closeSocket(socket);
    })
}

// Create a new server and provide a callback for when a connection occurs
var server = net.createServer(newSocket);

// Listen on port 8888
server.listen(8888);
```